# use numpy to make a collection dictionary for some statistical objects

Tags: numpy, dictionary, collections, statistics

I want to use numpy to make a collection dictionary for some statistical objects and the simplified state is as follows.

There are respectively a scalar-array noted as 
      `a = np.array([n1,n2,n3...])`
and a 2D-array as 
      `b = np.array([[q1_1,q1_2],[q2_1,q2_2],[q3_1,q3_2]...])`

For each element `ni` in `a`, I want to pick out all the elements `qi([qi_1,qi_2])` that contain `ni` in `b` and make a `dict` with the `key` as `ni` to collect them.

I have recorded a clumsy method for this purpose (assume that `a` and `b` are determined) into the following codes as:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([i+1 for i in range(100)])
b = np.array([[2*i+1,2*(i+1)] for i in range(50)])
dict = {}
for i in a: dict[i] = [j for j in b if i in j]
```

There's no doubt, that when `a` and `b` are large, this will be very slow.
Is there any other efficient way to replace the above one? 
Seeking your help!

Answer (score 0):

Numpy arrays allow elementwise comparison:

```
equal = b[:,:,np.newaxis]==a #np.newaxis to broadcast
# if one of the two is equal, we will include this element
index = np.logical_or(equal[:,0], equal[:,1])
# indexing by a boolean array to get the result
dictionary = {i: b[index[:,i]] for i in range(len(a))}
```

As a final remark: Are you sure you want to use a dictionary? By this you lose a lot of the numpy advantages

Edit, answer to your comment:

With a and b this large, equal will have size 10^10, which makes 8*10^10 bytes, which is approximately 72 G. That's why you get this error.

The main question you should ask is: Do I really need this big arrays? If yes, are you sure, that the dictionary will not be to large as well?

The problem can be solved, by not computing everything at once, but in `n` times, `n` should be about 72/16 (the proportion in memory) in your case. However having n a little bit larger will probably speed up the process:

```
stride = int(len(b)/n)
dictionary = {}
for i in range(n):
    #splitting b into several parts
    equal = b[n*stride:(n+1)*stride,:,np.newaxis]==a 
    index = np.logical_or(equal[:,0], equal[:,1])
    dictionary.update( {i: b[index[:,i]] for i in range(len(a))})
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, your codes are much fast than mine but still give the 'memories error' when a and b are large (e.g. a=100000 and b=50000 with RAM as 16G), whereas my codes in this condition are not working any more. How to improve your codes to stop that error?

Comment: @zgfu1985 I adapted the code, this should solve the problem, think about whether you actually need so large arrays

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your idea. It can solve completely my problem. Your core concept is to make a comparison of a and b and to get the Boolean array as the result. So, it is much fast to use this Boolean index for the array b to bulid the dictionary. Follow this idea, I rewrite your codes in my own way as that

```
dict = {}
for item in a:
    index_left, index_right = (b[:,0]==item), (b[:,1]==item)
    index = np.logical_or(index_left, index_right)
    dict[item] = dict[index]
```

These codes are still not faster than yours but can avoid the 'memories error' even in large a and b(eg. a=100000 and b=200000)